# Move artboard without changing contents position

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Often when I move an artboard in Illustrator using the mouse, the contents end up having moved half or 1 pixel within the artboard. Is there a setting or something else I can do to prevent the artboard's contents from moving in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make certain the "Move Artwork" option is not depressed before moving the artboard.

[image: Move artboard]

It will be a dark button or a light button. You want it to be a light button if you want artwork to stay in place while the artboard moves around under it.

### Edited to add:

In addition, you'll want to select the artwork and check the Align to Pixel Grid option on the Transform panel.

[image: Transform panel]

Art may shift and snap to the nearest pixel if this option is selected. It's designed to help prevent anti-aliased, blurry, strokes when creating content designed for the web.

Comment: That option is already selected. This does not stop the content to randomly move 1 or to pixels within the artboard after dragging - I FH Adobe

Comment: @RunLoop I've updated my answer with additional information which may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your artwork doesn't shift at all:

- Switch off 'Move/Copy Artwork with Artboard'
- Cut the artwork (⌘X)
- Move the artboard to where you want it
- Paste with 'Paste in Front' (⌘F) which pastes the artwork in the same co-ordinates as when they were cut.

Unfortunately this is the only way to make sure your artwork doesn't shift. Very annoying having to go back and shift everything back into place. Hope they fix this bug with the next release, I've logged this bug far too many times.